# Android Native Unit test Coverage for cpp via gcov and lcov

Tags: code-coverage

I am trying to run `lcov` and `gcov` on android platform for unit test coverage.
I am able to generate `.gcno` file and `.gcda` file successfully via the flags.

### Android.mk

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -g -O0 --coverage 
                -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage

LDFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
LOCAL_LDLIBS := --coverage
```

And I have made sure `gcov` and `gcc` are same version in my case 4.9 but I get this weird

```
error:file.gcno:version '402*', prefer '409*'
```

BR
M S Kha

Comment: Hello, it's actually not a blocking problem, I've got the same problem, but report generation is all right.

Comment: Thanks for the response but i get an empty report generated.

Comment: I get the error as mentioned :
geninfo: ERROR: file.gcno: reached unexpected end of file

Comment: Are you sure to use the same version of gcc and lcov?

Comment: In env i can see :
TARGET_GCC_VERSION=4.9 
after compiling with the above flags mentioned i get generated file.gcno 
and after executing 
/usr/bin/gcov-4.9  file.gcno
file.gcno:version '402*', prefer '409*'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
And loc version in the system is 
lcov: LCOV version 1.10

Comment: so I can see:
Segmentation fault (core dumped) ==> Are you sure you code is OK?
 And loc version in the system is lcov: LCOV version 1.10 
Lcov Version 1.10 and GCC version 4.9?
Are you sure it's compiled with the same version of GCC and lcov?
gcc --version   
gcov --version
?

Comment: Yes .. the code works fine when i run the unit test. Only the gcno files causes core dump when run with gcov ..
one more question the code i m compiling is c++  code is that a point of concern ??
and is there a way to validate the the code is compiled with GCC 4.9 ??
i have crossed check only the env and loc -v which shows the vesrions as expected.

Comment: some more details since i m building android source code .. i m using clang i suppose correct me if i m wrong here
and i m using mm tool to build via Android.mk files .

Comment: you can validate your GCC version with gcc --version ;)
normally there is no problem with CPP.
Concerning the dump, when you compile in gcov mode, it's with no optimization, so when you run your UT, is it on the code compiled in gcov mode? 
This is strange...

Comment: Okay i have found the cause the file.gcno is getting compiled with gcc version 4.2
i have validated this by running strings command on file.gcno , it prints oncg*204 :402* gcno .. but now i dnt know from where this is gcc version is getting set ..is there a way to choose gcc compiler version in Android.mk file ??

Comment: Hi @ShabazKhan, I'm trying to generate code coverage for native components in aosp. Could you please point me to some git projects with sample or references ??? With soong build system, it generates .gcnodir extension which I'm not able to use for coverage.

Comment: Did u check .gcno file in the path 
product/xxx/obj_x86/NATIVE_TESTS/xx_intermediates/
Try compiling with LOCAL_LDLIBS := --coverage